# Does the class of an xml configuration file need to match an actual class used in the application?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

For a configuration file in XML that you are using to store application settings, does it's class object need to be one of the classes that is used within the application, or do you create a special configuration class and the translate the values inside you application to the other objects that use those values?

For example

Say I want to keep track of these 3 settings for a product

```
Name
ID
Color
```

So My config file looks something simple like

```
<Product>
  <Name>product1</Name>
  <ID>2343435</ID>
  <Color>Blue</Color>
</Product>
```

But my Product class that I'm using in the application has many more properties and methods

like

```
class Product{

string Name;
string Color;
int ID;
bool isObsolete;
SpecialType ProductProperty;

Product(){}

ObsoleteProduct(){

//do stuff
}

OtherMethod(){

//Do stuff
}

}
```

So then am I supposed to make XML representation from the actual Product class I'm using, or do I use the simpler form that only contains the settings I care about?  Because if I use the simpler form, then I'll have two classes, and I'll need to move the values between objects.

Answer (score 0):

The xml serialization and deserialization can be configured a lot using attributes, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For instance, properties can be omitted from serialization, the names of properties can be explicitly specified and the serialization styles for array types can be selected.

Furthermore, the access on array types is done via the `ICollection`  interface, which permits to provide additional logic on insertion of elements, which is discussed in [this article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/06/12/c-parentchild-relationship-and-xml-serialization/).